# How do i use a variable from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi im having a problem with this i tried for 2 Days now but i don't know how to fix it. Im a beginner in C# and hope you can help me.
Im trying to use a variable from another script but the console keeps sending me an error:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
PlayerCombat.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D collision) (at Assets/Scrips/PlayerCombat.cs:52)

public int attackDmg = 2; //Diffrent Script

public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            PlayerTakeDamage(currentPlayerHp, GetComponent<Enemy>().attackDmg);
        }
    }

static void PlayerTakeDamage(int currentPlayerHp, int attackDmg)
    {
        currentPlayerHp -= attackDmg;
        if (currentPlayerHp <= 0)
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The

```
GetComponent<Enemy>()
```

is on another object, you can call it if you

### **1**

Create a public variable and add the **enemy** object

```
public GameObject enemy;
```

And then after you dragged your enemy inside it in the inspector you can:

```
enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>()
```

Without problems

### **2**

The second thing you can do is just declaring the enemy object

```
GameObject enemy;
```

And in the Start() you can

```
enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy");
```

But for this, you need to add a tag in the inspector for the enemy.

After this you can access the enemy as before.